# How to put variable data in array, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created a block to iterate and get the a href values. How can I put each value (each elements value) inside an array?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("title");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(elements[i].href);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `Array.prototype.push()`.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    arr.push(elements[i].href);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `foreach`, here is an example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
var arr = [];

elements.forEach(function(val){
    arr.push(val.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

And for jquery:

```
var elements = $(".title");
var arr = [];

elements.forEach(function(val){
    arr.push($(val).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("title");
var list = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    list.push(elements[i].href);
}

console.log(list);
```

```html
<a class="title" href="test1"></a>
<a class="title" href="test2"></a>
```